# Maximize algebraic trigonometric function

Tags: mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

I'm trying to maximize an algebraic function containing trigonometric functions:

$$\mathrm{sol}=\frac{\sin\theta \cos(\alpha +\beta)\cos(\theta+\alpha+\phi)\cos\bar{\delta}}{\cos^2\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta+\theta)\sin(\bar{\delta}+\theta+\phi)}$$

```
sol = (Sin[\[Theta]] Cos[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]] Cos[\[Theta] + \[Alpha] + \[Phi]] Cos[\[Delta]])/(Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 Cos[\[Alpha] + \[Beta] + \[Theta]] Sin[\[Delta] + \[Theta] + \[Phi]])
```

where

$$\bar{\delta}=\delta \qquad \text{if } \theta \leq \pi/2-\phi$$
while
$$\bar{\delta}=-\delta \qquad \text{if } \theta > \pi/2-\phi$$

I want to find the optimal $\theta$ that maximizes `sol`.

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in the range $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$, while $0<\phi<\pi/4$ and $0<\delta<\phi$ (thus, $-\phi<\bar{\delta}<\phi$).

$\theta$ is constrained as follows:

$$\max\{0,-\pi/2-\alpha-\beta\}<\theta<\pi/2-\alpha-\beta$$

$$-\bar{\delta}-\phi<\theta<\pi-\bar{\delta}-\phi$$

An analytical optimization can be found in the literature:

$$ \mathrm{OptimSol} = \frac{ \cos(\phi + \alpha)^2 \cos\delta}{\cos^2\alpha \cos(\delta - \alpha)\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{\sin(\phi + \delta) \sin(\phi - \beta)}{\cos(\delta - \alpha)\cos(\alpha + \beta)}}\right)^2} $$

Where the optimal $\theta$ has already been substituted.

```
optimsol = Cos[\[Phi] + \[Alpha]]^2/(Cos[\[Alpha]]^2*
    Cos[\[Delta] - \[Alpha]]*(1 + 
       Sqrt[Sin[\[Phi] + \[Delta]]*
         Sin[\[Phi] - \[Beta]]/(Cos[\[Delta] - \[Alpha]]*
            Cos[\[Alpha] + \[Beta]])])^2)*Cos[\[Delta]]
```

I tried to perform the maximization with Mathematica (since I'm interested in the optimal parameter $\theta$ as a function of the free parameters and want to later solve an extended version of this formula, for which I don't have an analytical solution)

What I first tried was something like

```
Maximize[{sol, Max[0, -Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta]] < \[Theta] < Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta], -\[Delta] - \[Phi] < \[Theta] < Pi - \[Delta] - \[Phi]}, \[Theta]]
```

and some other variations without constraints. However, I did not have success in maximizing the function.

As @user64494 correctly pointed out in the comments, I was missing something in my definition. It turned out to be the nonlinear definition of $\bar{\delta}$. Is it somehow possible to consider it for an algebraic maximization? I guess rather not, and it would be better to write two different solutions to be used with different constraints.

I'll try this now and will post here the updated solution.

Comment: Sorry, I had to incrementally expand my question through edits, because I was getting an error that my answer contained code that was not properly formatted, but did not really see where (I still have no idea what the problem was, probably some tabs in a latex region).

Comment: Something to adjust: `sol` approaches infinity if `\[Theta]`  tends to `-\[Delta]-[Phi]` from above. This is confirmed for `\[Alpha] = Pi/8; \[Beta] = Pi/8; \[Delta] = Pi/6; \[Phi] = Pi/12;
 Maximize[{sol, 
  Max[0, -Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta]] < \[Theta] < 
   Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta], -\[Delta] - \[Phi] < \[Theta] < 
   Pi - \[Delta] - \[Phi], \[Theta] > -Pi, \[Theta] <= Pi, 
  Pi/4 > {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Delta]} > 0}, \[Theta]]` .

Comment: @user64494 Thanks for your feedback. The parameters chosen in your example are actually inadmissible, since you have $\delta>\phi$. Otherwise, I think the bounds are correctly set. The case $\theta\to-\delta-\phi$ is indeed excluded.

Comment: Taking `\[Alpha] = Pi/8; \[Beta] = Pi/8; \[Delta] = Pi/24; \[Phi] = Pi/12;`, one obtains `Maximize[{sol, 
  Max[0, -Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta]] < \[Theta] < 
   Pi/2 - \[Alpha] - \[Beta], -\[Delta] - \[Phi] < \[Theta] < 
   Pi - \[Delta] - \[Phi], \[Theta] > -Pi, \[Theta] <= Pi, 
  Pi/4 > {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Delta]} > 0}, \[Theta]]` produces `{\[Infinity], {\[Theta] -> \[Pi]/4}}`. Your " The case θ→−δ−ϕ is indeed excluded. "  is not grounded.

Comment: @user64494 Yep, sorry, I see your point now. I actually omitted a quite important part of the solution. I now updated the question. If you have further observations, you're more than welcome! Thanks